# Free electromagnetic field BV action

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory

I am trying to write down the extended BV-action of the free electromagnetic field in a physicist notation, but I don't find it anywhere. I found the following formula in example 3.1. of the paper   [Remarks on Local Symmetry Invariance in  Perturbative Algebraic Quantum Field Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00023-014-0312-x) , by Kasia Rejzner:
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal{L}_{M}(f)(A,B,C,\bar{C})=-\frac{1}{2} \left \langle f F,F \right \rangle_{g} - \left \langle f dC, \frac{\delta}{\delta A} \right \rangle + i \left \langle fB,\frac{\delta}{\delta \bar{C}} \right \rangle - i \left \langle f d \bar{C},dC \right \rangle_{g}-\left \langle fB,*^{-1}d *A- \frac{1}{2} B \right \rangle_{g},
\end{equation}
where $$\left \langle u,v \right \rangle_{g}:=\int_{M} u \wedge *v,$$ $F=dA$, $B$ is the Nakanishi Lautrup field, $C$ is the ghost and $\bar{C}$ is the antighost. Explicitly, the extended configuration space reads:
\begin{equation*}
    \mathfrak{C}(M):=\Omega^{1}(M) \bigoplus C^{\infty}(M) \bigoplus C^{\infty}(M)[1] \bigoplus C^{\infty}(M)[-1].
\end{equation*}
Up to my understanding, this is a completely coordinate-independent formulation. How could one write this down explicitly in a physicist notation, using integrals? I tried writing the following:
\begin{equation}
S^{ED}=\int_{M}\left[\frac{1}{2} A_\mu\left(\square A^\mu-\partial^\mu \partial_\nu A^\nu\right)-A^{* \nu} \partial_\nu C \right],
\end{equation}
which would be the first two terms (I think), but I don't know how to rewrite the other terms. The formula I wrote is in accordance with a special case of the formula found [in this thesis](https://www.theorie.physik.uni-muenchen.de/TMP/theses/sebastian_albrecht.pdf), equation 4.25. Could anyone hint on how to rewrite the full Lagrangian in a physics notation/in coordinates?

Is the Nakanishi-Lautrup field a scalar field?

Comment: What is the meaning of the angle brackets that don’t have a subscript $g$? And what is $f$?

Comment: I am not sure tbh. In the paper it is stated as a duality of vector spaces, but I don't fully understand that bracket. f is a test function, which we can ignore for physics notation.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of links, so it is possible to reconstruct links in case of link rot.